# Quarkus reactive and JDBC datasource connection pooling

Tags: quarkus

I'm using Quarkus and have a project with two default datasources connecting to the same database, one uses JDBC (Agroal) for a postgres copy operation, the other uses reactive (PgPool) for all other sql operations.

There's an option in quarkus `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_POOLING_ENABLED` that can be set to `false` to disable connection pooling for JDBC datasource. So my question is:

1. Does reactive and JDBC datasources share the same connection pool? If I disable the JDBC pooling, will it affect the reactive connection pool?
2. Is there a way to verify such behavior?

Thank you all.

Trying to figure out the behavior between reactive and JDBC datasource regarding connection pooling. Expecting that turning off the pooling for JDBC via the config `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_JDBC_POOLING_ENABLED` will not impact reactive connection pool.